# qemu-img VHD to raw image convert results in bad geometry:

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, qemu, vhd

Is anyone else able to reproduce this?  Using StarWind V2V Image Converter on Windows, I'm able to get a valid disk.img file, so the source image.vhd is clean (pulled down from rackspace).  Is this a qemu-img bug under RHEL/CentOS 7?  ... any work-arounds?

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -i qemu

  qemu-img-1.5.3-86.el7_1.2.x86_64

# qemu-img convert -p image.vhd disk.img

# fdisk -l disk.img

  Disk disk.img: 10.2 GB, 10200121344 bytes, 19922112 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk label type: dos
  Disk identifier: 0x0007b3de

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  disk.img1   *        2048    19922943     9960448   83  Linux

  [ 2048 x 512 = 1048576 ]

# mount -o loop,offset=1048576 disk.img tmp/

  mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

# dmesg | tail

  [220700.705723] EXT4-fs (loop0):
  mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
  [220700.705739] EXT4-fs (loop0):
  bad geometry: block count 2490112 exceeds size of device (2490008 blocks)
```

Comment: Got the same issue using other converter (VBoxHD) and Ubuntu Server. Not sure if it's RHEL specific bug though..

Comment: That matter is that in order to properly convert a virtual machine you need to do some internal windows patching inside the VM. This option is present in StarWind V2V Converter.